# ASP.NET - Data transfer between two pages

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to transfer data from controls on page2 to GridView control on page1 upon pressing  button. (without using database)

I tried using DataTable for storing data and arrange them into columns/rows.

But when I click on button I get an exception saying: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." in line 58. --> DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

**Page2 c# code:**

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //Lastnosti
    public string IDizposoje
    {
        get { return TextBox3.Text; }
    }

    public string Ime
    {
        get { return TextBox1.Text; }
    }

    public string Priimek
    {
        get { return TextBox2.Text; }
    }

    public string DatumIzposoje
    {
        get { return Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString(); }
    }

    public string DatumVrnitve
    {
        get { return Calendar2.SelectedDate.ToString(); }
    }

    public string VrstaAvtomobila
    {
        get { return ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text; }
    }

    //Koda, ki se izvrši ob zagonu
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e, DataTable dt)
    {         
    }

    //Ob kliku na gumb "Prekliči" zapremo stran
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
        this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Close", "window.close()", true);
    }

    //Napolnimo tabelo s podatki
    public void NapolniTabelo(DataTable dt)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

        dr["ID"] = TextBox3.Text;
        dr["Ime"] = TextBox1.Text;
        dr["Priimek"] = TextBox2.Text;
        dr["Datum izposoje"] = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString();
        dr["Datum vrnitve"] = Calendar2.SelectedDate.ToString();
        dr["Vrsta avtomobila"] = ListBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NapolniTabelo((DataTable)Session["tabela"]);
        /*Session["ID"] = TextBox3.Text;
        Session["Ime"] = TextBox1.Text;
        Session["Priimek"] = TextBox2.Text;
        Session["Datum izposoje"] = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString();
        Session["Datum vrnitve"] = Calendar2.SelectedDate.ToString();
        Session["Vrsta avtomobila"] = ListBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();*/
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }

    //Ponastavimo gradnike
    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = "";
        TextBox2.Text = "";
        TextBox3.Text = "";
        Calendar1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;
        Calendar2.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;
        ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

**Page1 c# code:**

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private DataTable UstvariTabelo()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Ime", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Priimek", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Datum izposoje", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Datum vrnitve", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Vrsta vozila", typeof(string)));

        return dt;
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebForm1 druga = new WebForm1();
        DataTable tabela = UstvariTabelo();

        druga.NapolniTabelo(tabela);

        this.GridView1.Visible = true;
        this.GridView1.DataSource = ((DataTable)Session["tabela"]);
        this.GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Where is a code which stores a DataTable instance into the session?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting error, becouse Session["tabela"] is empty. So insted of this code:

```
(DataTable)Session["tabela"]
```

Always use safe property:

```
public DataTable tabela
{

   get
   {
      if(HttpContext.Current.Session["tabela"] == null)
      {
           HttpContext.Current.Session["tabela"] = new DataTable ("tableName");
      }
      return HttpContext.Current.Session["tabela"] as DataTable;
   }
   set
   {
      HttpContext.Current.Session["tabela"] = value;
   }
}
```

So you will never get null DataTable.

Comment: @cvenko I have tried your code and exception was on "dr["Vrsta avtomobila"]" which does not exists. DataRow dr = dt.NewRow(); works fine

Answer (score 0):

```
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
```

It is raising exception because datatable object (dt) is not in memory and you are trying to access it. In order to persist it across two pages, you can use session variables. For ex:

In page 1:

```
DataTable dt =  UstvariTabelo(); //I think this method is returning data table in page 1
//load data into dt
Session["test"]  = dt; //save it into a session variable
```

In page 2, you can retrieve the saved session value

```
if(Session["test"]!=null)
{
  DataTable dt = (DataTable) Session["test"];
}
```

Also in your page 1 code, you are not assigning any session variable before retrieving it on page 2.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebForm1 druga = new WebForm1();
        DataTable tabela = UstvariTabelo();

        druga.NapolniTabelo(tabela);

        this.GridView1.Visible = true;
        Session["tabela"] = tabela;//<--------assign it to session
        this.GridView1.DataSource = tabela;
        this.GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Done it, still throwing same exception, but on next line, where i assign values

Comment: There is no row named "Vrsta avtomobila", so there exception will be thrown at dr["Vrsta avtomobila"]. Try to debug the flow and add "dt" object to watch window, to see exactly what it contains.