# ASP.NET - Passing session data from page 2 to page1

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two pages. On page2, I manually enter values to controls and than assign these values to properties. When I click "Confirm" on page2, I start session(i guess) with the following method:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AssignValues();

        //Start data sessions
        Session["ID"] = IDizposoje;
        Session["Ime"] = Ime;
        Session["Priimek"] = Priimek;
        Session["DatumIzposoje"] = DatumIzposoje;
        Session["DatumVrnitve"] = DatumVrnitve;
        Session["VrstaVozila"] = VrstaVozila;

        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
```

What I would like you to help me with, is showing that data in gridview on page1 in columns. I have 6 properties and therefore, 6 columns.

How could that be achieved?

Comment: You want to use a `GridView` for a single record or are these properties collections? You could use a `DataTable` instead, store that in session and use it as `DataSource` for the `GridView`.

Comment: `When I click "Confirm" on page2, I start session(i guess)`. You are guessing wrong. The session starts when the user first gets on the site and ends when the session times out (or forcefully cleared).

Comment: Where do I create the DataTable? In page1 or page2?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET - Data transfer between two pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662386/asp-net-data-transfer-between-two-pages)

Answer (score 1):

You don't start the `Session` when you assign something to it. The session starts immediately   when the user visits the first page of the site.

You want to use a `GridView` for a single record or are these properties collections? 
You could create a [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t31h6yhs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead in `Page2`, store that in session and use it as `DataSource` for the `GridView`.

in "Default.aspx"

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
         DataTable table = (DataTable) Session["TblIzposoje"];
         GridView1.DataSource = table;
         GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

That would work directly if the `GridView` has set `AutogenerateColumns` to `true`.